# How to start an Android application inside my application? (example provided)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I found some launchers that are able to run installed apps inside their own activity. ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lwi.android.flapps )

This launcher adds their own functions like maximize, minimize etc. I guess they are creating widgets (because they need drawing over apps permission) and running inside them. But how :)

Can you show me how I can run another android application inside my own activity, widget etc. like this app did ?

Best,
Kerg

Comment: It's not running other apps. All the "apps" that it runs are included within the single app.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i can run apps installed in my device. Not only apps included in their app. It can able to run other apps too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following documentation should help you out with learning how to get your app to interact with other apps: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents

Especially interesting to you would be the section on sending the user to another app: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending